# PHP command to execute powershell script as admin

Tags: php, powershell, xampp

I want to run PowerShell script as admin from `PHP`. I am using below command to run the script, but it does not get executed as admin.

Any help how to get this working ?
I am using older version of XAMP.

```
$output=shell_exec('C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -command E:\XAMPP_DV\htdocs\project\lib\pwdreset.ps1 ' . $user . " " . $pwd);
```

Comment: Why are you using `-Command` to run a script?

Comment: he command I have provided in my query works, but the issue is it does not execute the script as admin. So I want to force the script to execute as admin from PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb and assume you don't have policies set up properly:

```
$output = shell_exec('powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -File "E:\XAMPP_DV\htdocs\project\lib\pwdreset.ps1" ' . $user . ' ' . $pwd);
```

In almost all cases, the path to `powershell.exe` is in the PATH environment variable, and the `ExecutionPolicy` is set to `RemoteSigned` by default.

Answer (score 0):

From [Microsoft TechNet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/acf70a31-ceb4-4ea5-bac1-be2b25eb5560/how-to-run-as-admin-powershellps1-file-calling-in-batch-file?forum=winserverpowershell) the following solution is suggested

```
$output=shell_exec('powershell -noprofile -command "&{ start-process powershell -ArgumentList -noprofile -file E:\XAMPP_DV\htdocs\project\lib\pwdreset.ps1 ' . $user . ' ' . $pwd . ' -verb RunAs}"');
```

Comment: You're missing a space before `-Verb` and your `-ArgumentList` argument is formatted wrong.  You need to separate arguments with a comma or they're seen as different arguments.

Comment: Edited my comment, see. Also need to quote those arguments or it'll think they're commands.  Suddenly your syntax gets very confusing very fast trying to execute this way

Comment: I couldn't duplicate what the original poster was trying to do so I based my answer on what was presented in the TechNet article. It was a bit confusing out of the box. Please edit my answer as you feel is needed.

Comment: The command I have provided in my query works, but the issue is it does not execute the script as admin. So I want to force the script to execute as admin from PHP.

Comment: And what is provided in both answers should do just that. Have you tried either one of them?

Comment: Below are content of powershell script, and I am passing wrong ID, so the If statement should get executed.                             
$username = $args[0];
$pass = $args[1];
$global:ustat = "";
$global:pwdstat = "";

if (-not [bool] (Get-ADUser -Filter { SamAccountName -eq $username })) {
        
        $global:ustat = "false";
        Write-Host "User ${username} does not exist"
}