# Php exec Powershell script Azure AZ commands do not run, all the other functions do

Tags: php, azure, powershell, exec

My PHP script

```
exec('powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -NoProfile -InputFormat none -file "..\..\scripts\addcustomer.ps1"', $output);
```

AZ function in the script:

```
$file = “$PSScriptRoot\Azure\pass.txt”
$azureuser = “user@contoso.com”
$Password = Get-Content $file | ConvertTo-SecureString
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential($azureuser, $Password)
Login-AzAccount -Credential $credential
New-AzDnsRecordSet -Name "$name" -RecordType A -ZoneName "contoso.co" -ResourceGroupName "RG" -Ttl 3600 -DnsRecords (New-AzDnsRecordConfig -IPv4Address "$ipaddress")
```

The $output does not display any output of this function. I confirm that if I run the script manually, everything works.

Many thanks.

Comment: You may need to check the PHP INI settings because `exec()` and other functions such as `system()` or `passthru()` may be disabled. This is set by `disable_functions = "exec, system"`.

Comment: @PatrickJanser Thanks for your reply. I have checked the **php.ini** and there are no disabled functions declared `disable_functions =`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `exec($your_command, $output, $error_code)` and see what `$error_code` contains. It may just be because `powershell.exe` isn't in the PATH env variable in PHP.

Try to put the full path to your PowerShell executable, typically something like this:

```php
<?php

// A default powershell path in case "where powershell" doesn't work.
define('POWERSHELL_EXE', 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe');

// Find the path to powershell with the "where" command.
$powershell_exe = exec('where powershell');
if ($powershell_exe === false) {
  $powershell_exe = POWERSHELL_EXE;
}

// Also check that the path to your script can be found.
// If it doesn't then you can use realpath() to get the
// full path to your script.
$cmd = $powershell_exe .
       ' -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -NoProfile -InputFormat none' .
       ' -file "..\..\scripts\addcustomer.ps1"';

$last_line = exec($cmd, $full_output, $error_code);

// Then check if $last_line !== false and check $error_code to see
// what happened.
var_export([
  '$cmd' => $cmd,
  '$last_line' => $last_line,
  '$full_output' => $full_output,
  '$error_code' => $error_code,
]);
```

Another important point: **Has the user running your PHP code enought rights to do what you are doing in your PS1 script?**

You may need to run your PowerShell script with elevation privilege or another user. I never did that but perhaps this topic could help:
[PHP command to execute powershell script as admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49562643/php-command-to-execute-powershell-script-as-admin)

Comment: This is the output where the function is run: ` 59 => '', 60 => '', 61 =>` and this is the final error code `'$error_code' => 0, ` . All the other functions in the script run with no problems. ?If I manually run the script, all is good including the AZ dns function.

Comment: Well, I suppose your PHP isn't running with the same user as the one you are launching your powershell script manually. Perhaps you have to do something about the rights of the user running PHP, probably in IIS or Apache, depending on your config.

Comment: Jenser Well spotted my friend. So to fix it I run the Apache service as the same user I run powershell as.

Comment: @DanielB Ok, changing the user is effectively a solution ;-) Just be aware that your PHP app could have too many privileges and it could be not so secure. The best would be to find a solution just to let PHP run this command with more privileges but not other things such as changing binaries, admin settings, services, etc. The server could get compromized more easily if PHP can change too many things.